# Certificates/Keys exchange for a webpage

Tags: security, networking

What type of certificates or keys are exchanged between a client and a server when it loads a webpage or website ?

Answer (score 1):

Only the server's public key and the client's public key are exchanged.

The following occurs when a browser is connection to an HTTPS enabled website / service:

**Client Hello**

The client sends the SSL version number, cipher settings, session-specific data.

**Server Hello**

The server responds with the SSL version number, cipher settings, and the Server’s Certificate (Public Key).

**Authentication and Pre-Master Secret**

The client now authenticates the server certificate, and depending on the cipher the client creates a pre-master secret for the session.

The client encrypts data with the server's public key and sends the encrypted pre-master secret to the server.

**Decryption and Master Secret**

The server now uses its private key to decrypt the pre-master secret.

Both the server and client perform steps to generate the master secret with the agreed cipher.

**Generate Session Keys**

Both the client and the server now use the master secret to generate the session keys. The session keys are symmetric keys used to encrypt and decrypt information exchanged during the session.

**Encryption with Session Key**

At this point both server and client exchange messages to inform that future messages will be encrypted.

In short, there are 4 keys involved. The server's public and private key and the client's public and private key. The client gives it's public key to the server and the server gives it's public key to the client. The private keys are never transmitted or shared with anyone, they remain on the client and server, thus they are private.

Usually certificates are signed by a third party such as GoDaddy or Verisign. This gives the client reassurance that the server who issued the public key to the client is indeed who they say they are. (However beware, there is always the possibility of man in the middle attacks)